# Basic sort function, having difficulty initializing my array correctly

Tags: c, gdb

I'm trying to create a simple application that takes a list of numbers from stdin and sorts them by casting all of the variables into 'semi' sorted lists by taking a simple average of the numbers and casting them into two arrays:

```
(a[] is <= avg)
(b[] is > avg)
```

My plan is then to sort my two lists, and then merge them. (I also understand that any optimization that I'm getting through this effort is most likely lost by not keeping it simple).

Here's my code and I'll follow up with two questions below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool compare(val1,val2)
{
    if(val1 > val2){return false;}
    else{return true;}
}

int average(char *array[],int count)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<count;i++){
        int temp = atoi(array[i]);
        total = temp+total;
    }
    int avg = total/(count-1);
    return avg;    

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //produce average for argv array excluding *argv[0]
    int avg = average(argv,argc);
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        //print unsorted list for debugging
        //TODO remove this
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    }

    //setup int arrays (-2 because argc = count +1 & because of average one number will always be > or < average.
    int a[argc-2];
    int b[argc-2];
    //start counters for a=below avg b =above avg
    int acount = 0; 
    int bcount = 0;

    //cycle through argv[i] and cast values to new arrays a && b
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        //temp variable to avoid excessive atoi()
        int temp = atoi(argv[i]);
        if(temp <= avg){
            a[acount] = temp;
            acount++;
        }
        else{
            b[bcount] = temp;
            bcount++;        
        }
        //print temp for debugging
        //TODO remove this.
        printf("%d\n",temp);            
    }
    // sort a
    for(int i = 1; i <acount; i++){
        int temp;
        if(compare(a[i],a[i+1])){}
        else{
           temp = a[i];
           a[i] = a[i+1];
           a[i+1] = temp;   
        }
        printf("\n%d\n",a[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

1. I'm having difficulty with gdb trying to debug my code. I'm trying
   to break at `printf("\n%d\n",a[i]);` and run the following with
   these results:

   ```
   (gdb) b 69
   (gdb) r 1 2 3
   Breakpoint 1, main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff184) at work.c:69
   69          printf("\n%d\n",a[i]);
   (gdb) info locals
   temp = 2
   i = 1
   avg = 2
   acount = 2
   bcount = 1
   b = <optimized out>
   (gdb) p a[i]
   No symbol "a" in current context.
   (gdb) p *argv[i]
   $1 = 49 '1'
   ```
2. What am I doing wrong here that `a[]` and `b[]` aren't storing the values as I'd hoped?

Comment: `int a[argc-2]; int b[argc-2];` --> `int a[argc-1]; int b[argc-2];`, `for(int i = 1; i <acount; i++){` --> `for(int i = 0; i <acount-1; i++){` /*and need nest loop */

Comment: You're only attempting to sort `a` and not attempting to sort `b` or merge `a` and `b`.  It's funny you don't print the average; it is crucial to the behaviour of the rest of the code.  Your sorting code only makes one pass through the `a` array.  That may be sufficient while there are but two elements in the array, but it is not sufficient when there are more.

Comment: (And you are obviously trying to debug optimized code.)